# SSL certificate in system store not trusted by Chrome

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-chrome

I have a gitlab server running in our company for which I have obtained a certificate signed by our company's CA. Since I can access the site from a machine within our domain without getting SSL errors, I'm assuming, that the server is configured correctly.

When working with my laptop, I of course did not have the company CA certificate. For example `openssl s_client -connect my.git.server:443` would return an "Error 19, self signed certificate in chain":

```
0 s:/C=REDACTED
   i:/DC=REDACTED/DC=REDACTED/CN=IssuingCA
 1 s:/DC=REDACTED/DC=REDACTED/CN=IssuingCA
   i:/CN=RootCA
 2 s:/CN=RootCA
   i:/CN=RootCA
```

So I accessed the server and exported the root CA cert. I then added it to my system store:

```
sudo su
cp RootCA /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/RootCA.crt
update-ca-certificates
```

Now openssl accepts it just fine (return code 0, ok). However, Google Chrome still complains:

> This server could not prove that it is my.git.server; its security certificate is not trusted by your **computer's operating system**.

Were it not for this message, I'd have figured that Chrome has its own certificate store and doesn't care for the OS. But it seems quite clear that the certificate **is** trusted by the OS and Chrome refers to it.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Is this just a quirk of Chrome that it doesn't respect the system certs, or am I missing something?

Comment: Chrome _does_ have its own certificate store.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There's no doubt about that, but does it also use the system store?

Comment: Again, Chrome uses its own certificate store.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, it wasn't clear that it *only* uses its own store. If that's the case, this is an answer I could accept.

Comment: [This page](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) tells Chrome uses NSS (Firefox does this, too, FWIW) so I'd say this all may depend on how NSS is configured on your Ubuntu. Still, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/248326) hints at that there is simply is no NSS-compatible system store on Ubuntu (the `/etc/ca-certificates` hierarchy is for software using OpenSSL (and may be also GnuTLS, I dunno)). So, while I don't have a definite answer for you, those are the pointers to investigate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Ubuntu, Chrome uses its own certificate store. You can import your RootCA.crt in Chrome's

settings -> privacy and security -> manage security keys -> manage certificates -> authorities

Note that updating ubuntu system certificate store by `update-ca-certificates` has no effect on Chrome.

Comment: spent about 2 hours trying to figure out why Chrome is ignoring system certificates, now it is clear, thank you!

Comment: and to install the certificate via the command line you may use:

sudo apt-get install libnss3-tools


certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "CP,CP," -n SomeName -i cert.crt